# Maximally distant orthogonal matrices

Tags: matrices, optimization, normed-spaces, orthonormal

I would like to construct a set of $k$ orthogonal matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with maximal summed pairwise distance (in terms of L2 operator norm).  Any ideas?  I am thinking of just doing SGD.  Is this something that has been studied?

We can restrict ourselves to determinant = 1, if that helps.  In that case, it seems like we would just get out the $k$-th roots of unity (up to a phase shift) for $n=2$.

Comment: OK, so SGD is not going to work OOTB because it won't maintain orthogonality (duh).

Comment: So one could also add a penalty term to encourage orthogonality ($M^TM - I$), but the problem I have now is passing the gradient through the computation of the operator norm (which is the largest eigenvalue).